# Given two sets of product ratings, how to test whether one product is better than the other?

Tags: probability, statistics, self-learning, hypothesis-testing

My wife and I are considering buying a soundbar. Two different soundbars stood out to us on Amazon. One had ~2000 reviews, at an average of 4.1 stars. The other had ~80 reviews, at an average of 4.3 stars.

What would be the best way to test the hypothesis that the "true mean" rating of the latter (product B) is higher than that of the former (product A)?

Comment: Unless you can get _standard deviations_ as well as averages, I see no way to test whether the two sample means are statistically significant. Also, there is no way to know if Amazon ratings are based on anything like random samples of knowledgeable users of soundbars.

Comment: You can see how many 1-,2-,3-, and 4-star reviews each product got, from which you can estimate sd.

Comment: OK then. With sample sizes, sample means, and sample SDs for ratings of each of two soundbars, you have the info necessary for a 2-sample t test. Sample sizes are probably large enough you don't need to worry about normality. There are two kinds of 2-sample t tests: pooled and Welch. I recommend Welch (because you have no reason to suppose pop SDs will be the same), but there will probably not be much diff btw the two. If you will post SD in a Comment for me, I'd probably be able to run it thru software. (With counts of nrs of stars a permutation test seems possible, but I think unnecessary.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can download the ratings, you can either do a T test (after calculating the SDs), or you can do a permutation test.

To do the permutation test, you would put the data in the form
\begin{pmatrix}
Product & Rating \\
A & \text{Rating}_{1A}\\ 
\dots & \dots\\ 
A & \text{Rating}_{1N_A} \\
B & \text{Rating}_{1B}\\ 
\dots & \dots\\ 
B & \text{Rating}_{1N_B}
\end{pmatrix}

Where $N_A$ and $N_B$ are the number of reviews for each product. Basically what you do is

1. Randomly shuffle the product rating column around while keeping the product label in the same spot
2. Calculate the difference in the new means associated with products A and B
3. Repeat 1. and 2. a million times (just do it a lot)
4. The absolute observed difference between the average rating for products A and B is 0.2, so for two sided test, you just calculate the proportion of reshuffled mean differences that have an absolute difference greater than 0.2

Comment: This is a cool idea, I will code it up in R this weekend.

Comment: Oh clarification. Textbook version of permutation tests permutes the labels, and not the values. Since this is a two group test it should give you the same thing, but just need to pre-emptively save face